# Node.js - Express & mysql TypeError: res.json is not a function although insert is successful

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Although I have a successful insert I get an error (TypeError: res.json is not a function) when I want to return a json message upon. This is my setup:

```
const express = require('express');

module.exports = {
    signup: async (req, res, next) => {

        const { email, username, password } = req.value.body;

        const connection = require('../config/dbconnection');

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email = ?",[email], function(err, rows) {
            if (rows.length) {
                return res.json({ err: 'Email already exist'});
            } else {

                var newUserMysql = {
                    email: email,
                    username: username,                 
                    password: password  
                };

                var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_users ( email, username, password ) values (?,?,?)";

                connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.email, newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, res, rows) {

                    if(err){
                        console.log('Insert error');
                        //res.json({ err: 'Insert error'});
                    } else {
                        console.log('Insert successful');
                        return res.json({ 'success': 'Insert successful'});
                        //return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    }

                });
            }
        });

}
```

How can I return a json on successfull insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function's `res` parameter is hidden by the `res` return value from the `connection.query` call.
Rename the `res` parameter of this call to `result` (for example) and you should be fine:

```
connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.email, newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, result, rows) {
              if(err){
                    console.log('Insert error');
                    //res.json({ err: 'Insert error'});
                } else {
                    console.log('Insert successful');
                    return res.json({ 'success': 'Insert successful'});
                    //return done(null, newUserMysql);
                }
});
```

When you have nested scopes with conflicting variable names, the variable the closest (scope-wise) from where you reference this conflicting name will be used.

Comment: I changed it accordingly ... but result.json({ 'success': 'Insert successful'}); is still giving me an error: TypeError: result.json is not a function

Comment: You have to keep `res.json` here. Just change `function(err, res, rows)` to `function(err, result, rows)`. I updated my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining `res` in your `connection.query(insertQuery, [.....], function(err, res, rows) { ...})` function.

That `res` overrules the `res` from your express router within the scope of that function